# Justify the text in a richtextbox

Tags: textbox, vb6, richtextbox, justify

I know how to justify right center and left in both the text box and richtextbox, what I searched and found no answer for is Can you JUSTIFY the text just like in word or all those other programs? I tried using word pad then copied it and that worked fine it's just that when I wan't to be able to click a command button and justify the text so that the lines all line up i'm stopped,
The code I am using is right here

```
    Option Explicit

Private Const WM_USER As Long = &H400&
Private Const EM_GETOLEINTERFACE As Long = WM_USER + 60
Private Const EM_SETTYPOGRAPHYOPTIONS As Long = WM_USER + 202
Private Const TO_ADVANCEDTYPOGRAPHY As Long = 1

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageW" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal wMsg As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As Long, _
    ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Private Document As tom.ITextDocument

Private Sub cmdJustify_Click()
    'Justify the text of the first paragraph:

    'Select first paragraph in the document.
    With Document.Range(0, 0)
        .MoveEnd tomParagraph, 1
        .Para.Alignment = tomAlignJustify 'Apply justification.
        .Collapse tomStart 'Collapse the selection.
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim Unknown As Object

    SendMessage rtb.hWnd, EM_GETOLEINTERFACE, 0, VarPtr(Unknown)
    Set Document = Unknown
    SendMessage rtb.hWnd, _
                EM_SETTYPOGRAPHYOPTIONS, _
                TO_ADVANCEDTYPOGRAPHY, _
                TO_ADVANCEDTYPOGRAPHY

    rtb.LoadFile "Resources\Sample1.rtf"
End Sub
```

Comment: Is your `rtb` a RichTextBox?  Do you have a file named `Resources\Sample1.rtf`?  Because all you have done is copy and paste the example code from below and that code works with no issues at all here.

Comment: No.  Only RichEdit controls support `EM_SETTYPOGRAPHYOPTIONS` and the markup to have paragraphs with different alignment.  Edit controls are all or nothing and limited to left, right, or centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to send the underlying RichEdit control a `EM_SETPARAFORMAT` message, passing it a pointer to a [`PARAFORMAT2` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787942(v=vs.85).aspx) with `wAlignment = PFA_JUSTIFY`.

Or use TOM and `ITextPara.Alignment = tomAlignJustify` (see [tomAlignJustify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh768766(v=vs.85).aspx#tomAlignJustify)) or something.

Or barring that, look up the RTF markup and use `.SelRTF`?

Ok, you do have to turn on "advanced line breaking and line formatting" first.  After that it is pretty plain sailing though:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const WM_USER As Long = &H400&
Private Const EM_GETOLEINTERFACE As Long = WM_USER + 60
Private Const EM_SETTYPOGRAPHYOPTIONS As Long = WM_USER + 202
Private Const TO_ADVANCEDTYPOGRAPHY As Long = 1

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageW" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal wMsg As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As Long, _
    ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Private Document As tom.ITextDocument

Private Sub cmdJustify_Click()
    'Justify the text of the first paragraph:

    'Select first paragraph in the document.
    With Document.Range(0, 0)
        .MoveEnd tomParagraph, 1
        .Para.Alignment = tomAlignJustify 'Apply justification.
        .Collapse tomStart 'Collapse the selection.
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim Unknown As Object

    SendMessage RTB.hWnd, EM_GETOLEINTERFACE, 0, VarPtr(Unknown)
    Set Document = Unknown
    SendMessage RTB.hWnd, _
                EM_SETTYPOGRAPHYOPTIONS, _
                TO_ADVANCEDTYPOGRAPHY, _
                TO_ADVANCEDTYPOGRAPHY

    RTB.LoadFile "Resources\Sample1.rtf"
End Sub
```

Comment: But that is C++, while I need for vb 6?

Comment: There is no need for C++.  The first two can be done from a VB6 program and the third alternative most certainly can.

Comment: @Bob77: I'm not sure that you can send the control a EM_SETPARAMFORMAT message directly, since some of that functionality isn't in the 1.0 RTF spec.  I do know that the TOM trick works, though.

Comment: Pretty sure it works.  Remember that in modern times the VB6 RTB wraps a newer version of RichEdit (v. 3.0?) working in its "compatibility mode" and not the old RichEdit 1.0 itself.

Comment: Got error Private Document As tom.ITextDocument "User-Defined type not defined"

Comment: Your program needs a reference to the TOM type library ("tom").

Comment: I added the reference and then I got new error Set Document = Unknown "Type Mismatch" whats the cause of this?

Comment: Try `MsgBox TypeName(Unknown)` just before that.  Perhaps the result will help you see where you went wrong.

Comment: The message was "object" what is object and why is that a Type Mismatch error? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: @bob77 Ok, I tested it to see, and it all works.  I also commented out the code that sends the advanced typography message, and while everything ran, clicking the Justify button had no effect.  So, it looks like it is as you say: the SendMessage actually goes to the underlying OLE interface rather than the RTB control interface.  Nice trick!

Comment: @vbdevelp Try changing the name "Document" to something else, like myDocument.  You may have a reference to something that recognizes Document as a static object, that takes priority over your TOM reference.  You can also check the TypeName of Document to see.

Comment: @vbdevelp you might want to edit your original post and put the code you have in it.

Comment: you may change `VarPtr(Unknown)` to `ObjPtr(Unknown)`,

Comment: No, you don't want `ObjPtr()` here.  "Type Mismatch" is saying that the requested interface cannot be found, implying that your `Unknown` was never assigned a reference to an `IRichEditOle` object instance.  Perhaps you are using a different `SendMessage()` declaration?  You can also check that call for a failure (`0` returned).

Comment: `SendMessage()` is a function and can return a value indicating success or failure.  The snippet above discards that by calling it using "subroutine call" syntax since if properly coded failure is unlikely.  A `EM_GETOLEINTERFACE` request returns zero for failure and non-zero for success.  You should be looking all of these things up, not just trying to paste them into a program.

Comment: My send message() is SendMessage RTB.hWnd, EM_GETOLEINTERFACE, 0, VarPtr(Unknown) and that doesn't cause me an error is there a different send message I should use?

Comment: If it is failing then the function returns a 0 value.  It doesn't and can't raise an exception, you would need to check the returned result value.

Comment: @Bob77 i was trying to figure out your code again, and i cant seem to figure why it does not work, perhaps we have different versions of the richtextbox?

Comment: We aren't using the RichTextBox, but burrowing inside to the Win32 RichEdit control that it wraps.  So any difference would be at the OS level, not the OCX level.

Answer (score 1):

The RichText control in VB6 only directly supports rich text 1.0, which doesn't support justifying.  As Bob77 suggests, you can use TOM to do this. Essentially, you're tricking the control into exposing its iRichTextOLE interface directly, which gives you access to later RTF versions.  This is the code I use:

```
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
Private Const WM_USER = &H400&
Private Const EM_GETOLEINTERFACE = (WM_USER + 60)

Dim myIUnknown As IUnknown   
Dim tomDoc As ITextDocument  

Sub Form_Load()
    SendMessage(rtcMyControl.hwnd, EM_GETOLEINTERFACE, 0&, myIUnknown)
    tomDoc = myIUnknown
End Sub
```

This is essentially the same code as Bob77's code to get an ITextDocument reference, just another version of it. I only put it in to show the part that corresponds to the "use TOM" part of his answer, in case it helps to clarify that.  Personally, TOM is the way that I go if I need to do anything like what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by just setting a property. You have to do some more work on it and make your functions.

```
Private Declare Function SendMessageLong Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal HWND As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal HWND As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
Const WM_USER = &H400
Const EM_SETTYPOGRAPHYOPTIONS = WM_USER + 202
Const TO_ADVANCEDTYPOGRAPHY = 1
Const EM_SETPARAFORMAT = WM_USER + 71
Private Const PFA_LEFT = 1
Private Const PFA_RIGHT = 2
Private Const PFA_CENTER = 3
Private Const PFA_JUSTIFY = &H4
Const MAX_TAB_STOPS = 32
Private Type PARAFORMAT2
    cbSize                     As Long
    dwMask                     As Long
    wNumbering                 As Integer
    wEffects                   As Integer
    dxStartIndent              As Long
    dxRightIndent              As Long
    dxOffset                   As Long
    wAlignment                 As Integer
    cTabCount                  As Integer
    rgxTabs(MAX_TAB_STOPS - 1) As Long
    dySpaceBefore              As Long
    dySpaceAfter               As Long
    dyLineSpacing              As Long
    sStyle                     As Integer
    bLineSpacingRule           As Byte
    bOutlineLevel              As Byte
    wShadingWeight             As Integer
    wShadingStyle              As Integer
    wNumberingStart            As Integer
    wNumberingStyle            As Integer
    wNumberingTab              As Integer
    wBorderSpace               As Integer
    wBorderWidth               As Integer
    wBorders                   As Integer
End Type
Public Enum ERECParagraphAlignmentConstants
   ercParaLeft = PFA_LEFT
   ercParaCentre = PFA_CENTER
   ercParaRight = PFA_RIGHT
   ercParaJustify = PFA_JUSTIFY
End Enum
Private Const PFM_ALIGNMENT = &H8&

Private Function SetAlignment(lHwnd As Long, ByVal eAlign As ERECParagraphAlignmentConstants)
    Dim tP2 As PARAFORMAT2
    Dim lR As Long
    tP2.dwMask = PFM_ALIGNMENT
    tP2.cbSize = Len(tP2)
    tP2.wAlignment = eAlign
    lR = SendMessageLong(lHwnd, EM_SETTYPOGRAPHYOPTIONS, TO_ADVANCEDTYPOGRAPHY, TO_ADVANCEDTYPOGRAPHY)
    lR = SendMessage(lHwnd, EM_SETPARAFORMAT, 0, tP2)
End Function
```

**Usage**

> SetAlignment RichTextBox1.HWND, ercParaJustify

I have picked this code from teh Code Bank section of [VBForums](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?275310-VB6-Justify-text-in-RichTextBox)

I am posting the same code here because this is a really useful code.

Comment: Doesn't align anything! It stays the same, I used your usage thing and I got no error but I also go no result! I got the same result or really the no result from your link, do you have a idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: can you explain how this code works and maybe even upload a sample project with it working?

Comment: I am not using vb anymore. However, I used this code back in 2005 to have the text justified in a VB project that I was working on at that time and it worked for me at that time.

Comment: do i need any references? and this should work in vb6 if it works in vb5 right?